# The conductor of the Hilbert class field of a number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Suppose $K$ is a number field which is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $H(K)$ be the Hilbert class field of $K$. Also assume that $H(K)$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $Gal(H(K)/\mathbb{Q})$ abelian.

I want to prove that the conductors of $K$ as well as $H(K)$ are same. If $f(K)$ and $f(H(K))$ stand for the conductors of $K$ and $H(K)$, respectively then all I could establish is that $f(K) \mid f(H(K))$. How can I proceed to prove the other way?

Comment: If $p = \mathfrak P^e$ ramifies in $H(K)$ (with $e>1$), then $\mathfrak p := \mathfrak P \cap K$ is a prime of $K$, which is not ramified in the HCF $H(K)$, so it must be ramified over $p$. Thus $p \mid f(H_K) \implies p \mid f(K)$, but it doesn't quite mean $f(H_K) \mid f(K)$.

Comment: How did you show $f(K) \mid f(H_K)$ ?

Comment: How do you define the conductor of $K$?

Comment: By hypothesis, $H(K)$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ with abelian Galois group. Hence $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is a quotient of $Gal(H(K)/\mathbb{Q})$ and thus $K$ is an abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. By Kronecker-Weber theorem, $K \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The smallest such n is denoted here by $f(K)$.

Comment: @Watson $K \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{f(K)})$ and $K \subset H(K) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{f(H(K))})$. 

Hence by the minimality of the conductor, $K \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{f(K)}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{f(H(K))})$. It then follows that $f(K) \mid f(H(K))$.

Comment: Ok thank you. Where does this exercise come from (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: One of my friends was trying to explain something related to class fields to me and there he made this statement. I was trying to figure out the proof but failed to come up with one. He himself couldn't do it. We could prove only the $f(K) \mid f(H(K))$ part.

Comment: It is a bit misleading to assume that K is Galois at the beginning and abelian at the end. Anyway, what you need is that a class field contains the Hilbert class field if and only if the associated ideal group contains the principal ideals P  coprime to the conductor (or is contained in, I tend to get inclusions wrong when I do not think about these things carefully).So if K is associated to an ideal group H, the class field to the ideal group $H*P$ has the same conductor and contains the Hilbert class field.